# VSC - Powershell session - Timed out waiting for session file to appear

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

No idea how to solve this problem. Logs do not provide any useful informations.

```
9/11/2020 7:52:00 AM [NORMAL] - Visual Studio Code v1.49.0 64-bit
9/11/2020 7:52:00 AM [NORMAL] - PowerShell Extension v2020.6.0
9/11/2020 7:52:00 AM [NORMAL] - Operating System: Windows 64-bit
9/11/2020 7:52:00 AM [NORMAL] - Language server starting --
9/11/2020 7:52:00 AM [NORMAL] -     PowerShell executable: C:\Users\galgmapl\.dotnet\tools\pwsh.exe
9/11/2020 7:52:00 AM [NORMAL] -     PowerShell args: -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command Import-Module 'c:\Users\galgmapl\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-2020.6.0\modules\PowerShellEditorServices\PowerShellEditorServices.psd1'; Start-EditorServices -HostName 'Visual Studio Code Host' -HostProfileId 'Microsoft.VSCode' -HostVersion '2020.6.0' -AdditionalModules @('PowerShellEditorServices.VSCode') -BundledModulesPath 'c:\Users\galgmapl\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-2020.6.0\modules' -EnableConsoleRepl -StartupBanner "=====> PowerShell Integrated Console v2020.6.0 <=====
" -LogLevel 'Normal' -LogPath 'c:\Users\galgmapl\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-2020.6.0\logs\1599803520-7e29a521-770b-4023-b59e-0a1636f5fc961599803517422\EditorServices.log' -SessionDetailsPath 'c:\Users\galgmapl\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-2020.6.0\sessions\PSES-VSCode-8800-557813' -FeatureFlags @() 
9/11/2020 7:52:00 AM [NORMAL] -     PowerShell Editor Services args: Import-Module 'c:\Users\galgmapl\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-2020.6.0\modules\PowerShellEditorServices\PowerShellEditorServices.psd1'; Start-EditorServices -HostName 'Visual Studio Code Host' -HostProfileId 'Microsoft.VSCode' -HostVersion '2020.6.0' -AdditionalModules @('PowerShellEditorServices.VSCode') -BundledModulesPath 'c:\Users\galgmapl\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-2020.6.0\modules' -EnableConsoleRepl -StartupBanner "=====> PowerShell Integrated Console v2020.6.0 <=====
" -LogLevel 'Normal' -LogPath 'c:\Users\galgmapl\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-2020.6.0\logs\1599803520-7e29a521-770b-4023-b59e-0a1636f5fc961599803517422\EditorServices.log' -SessionDetailsPath 'c:\Users\galgmapl\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-2020.6.0\sessions\PSES-VSCode-8800-557813' -FeatureFlags @() 
9/11/2020 7:52:00 AM [NORMAL] - pwsh.exe started.
9/11/2020 7:52:00 AM [NORMAL] - Waiting for session file
9/11/2020 7:56:00 AM [NORMAL] - Timed out waiting for session file to appear.
9/11/2020 7:56:00 AM [NORMAL] - Language server startup failed.
9/11/2020 7:56:00 AM [ERROR] - The language service could not be started: 
9/11/2020 7:56:00 AM [ERROR] - Error: Timed out waiting for session file to appear.
```

Comment: I had a similar issue. VSCode tries to update Powershell modules, but when the powershellgallery is unavailable, the terminal hangs. My issue was solved by the network team, but i'm not a 100% which changes they made.